# no rows selected error after importin data into sql developer from excel ..csv file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

After successfully importing data from `excel` into `sql developer` when I type:

```
 select * from table_name
```

it says `no rows selected` whereas `excel` file has huge data (around 1000 records). Please help

Comment: How do you know the import was successful?

Comment: Try SQLLoader instead.

Comment: So you imported an Excel spreadsheet into a table in an Oracle database using SQL Developer, correct? Did you commit the changes?

Comment: Also, did you import only DDL or with data option?